# OpenLayers - Can't remove zoom control buttons, other controls simply lay on top

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I have a simple OpenLayers script with a Google map as the base layer.  By default the map has a + and - zoom control button, which I can't find how to get rid of.

I've added an empty controls array to the map options, but it still appears.  If I add any other controls, for example PanZoomBar, it just sits ontop of the + and - buttons, semi-obscuring them. The effect is the same whether I add PanZoomBar in the controls array or with map.addControl.

Here is what it looks like by default:
[image]

And with added PanZoomBar:
[image]

And here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Map test</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="google-v3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #map-container { width: 740px; height:770px; float: left }
        #map_canvas { width: 740px; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload='init();'>
<h2>Map Test</h2>

    <div id="map-container">
        <div id="map_canvas"/>    
    </div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){

        var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: "map_canvas"
        });

        // Base Layer
        var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google( 'Googlemap', {
            controls: [],
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            sphericalMercator:true
            //projection: "EPSG:900913",
        });
        map.addLayer(gmap);

        // Center map to center of UK
        var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-4.2, 54.6);
        var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        point.transform(proj, map.getProjectionObject());
        map.setCenter(point, 5);

        //map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());

    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help me get rid of the + and - buttons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution could be to initialize OL without controls.

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    controls: [],
    div: "map_canvas"
});
```

And now you can add your controls with

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
```

Or define controls on initialisation

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()],
    div: "map_canvas"
});
```

Comment: Aha! I see what I was doing wrong now.  I put controls[] into the gmap layer instead of the map initialization. Couldn't see the wood for the trees. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

how about replacing:

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

or adding some additional code:

```
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
```

take a look at this example:

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/controls.html

Comment: Changing the script source did sort out the problem with the controls, but it also gave a popup box saying stuff like 'Map Data Map data ©2013 GeoBasis-DE/BKG (©2009), Google' on each zoom or pan.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code a bit to make it work. I hope it will help.

Here is modified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Map test</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="google-v3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
#map-container {
    width: 740px;
    height:770px;
    float: left
}
#map_canvas {
    width: 740px;
    height: 100%
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body onload='init();'>
<h2>Map Test</h2>
<div id="map-container">
      <div id="map_canvas"/>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){

        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_canvas', {
                    controls: [
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false}),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink('permalink'),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
                    ],
                    numZoomLevels: 12

                });

        // Base Layer
        var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google( 'Googlemap', {
            controls: [],
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            sphericalMercator:true
            //projection: "EPSG:900913",
        });
        map.addLayer(gmap);

        // Center map to center of UK
        var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-4.2, 54.6);
        var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        point.transform(proj, map.getProjectionObject());
        map.setCenter(point, 5);

       // map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the default zoom with this:

```
map.removeControl(map.getControlsByClass('OpenLayers.Control.Zoom')[0]);
```

If you start with no controls then you'll lose the ability to move around the map by dragging the mouse pointer.